# Snowflake - Cumulative Range Window

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm attempting to do the following.

- create a `rank` based on a `24` hour window.
- sum by customer, rank and take the `min` date of a customers `rank`

to describe this in steps, I'd start with the following table.

| CUSTOMER | LAST_ORDER_DATE | TOTAL_ORDER_AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| customer_a | 2023-01-01 14:24:18.000000000 +00:00 | 250 |
| customer_a | 2023-01-02 10:24:18.000000000 +00:00 | 250 |
| customer_a | 2023-01-02 19:24:18.000000000 +00:00 | 900 |
| customer_b | 2023-01-01 14:24:18.000000000 +00:00 | 750 |
| customer_b | 2023-01-02 00:24:18.000000000 +00:00 | 800 |
| customer_b | 2023-01-02 10:24:18.000000000 +00:00 | 22 |

based on the `customers` first known date I'd like to create a 24 hour rolling sum

first I'd calculate some sort of arbitrary key to then group by at a later stage.

| CUSTOMER | LAST_ORDER_DATE | TOTAL_ORDER_AMOUNT | RANGE_48_HOUR_KEY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| customer_a | 2023-01-01 14:24:18.000000000 +00:00 | 250 | 1 |
| customer_a | 2023-01-02 10:24:18.000000000 +00:00 | 250 | 1 |
| customer_a | 2023-01-02 19:24:18.000000000 +00:00 | 900 | 2 |
| customer_b | 2023-01-01 14:24:18.000000000 +00:00 | 750 | 1 |
| customer_b | 2023-01-02 15:24:18.000000000 +00:00 | 800 | 1 |
| customer_b | 2023-01-02 19:24:18.000000000 +00:00 | 22 | 1 |

which would finally yield.

| CUSTOMER | DATE | TOTAL_ORDER_AMOUNT_SUM | RANGE_48_HOUR_KEY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| customer_a | 2023-01-01 | 500 | 1 |
| customer_a | 2023-01-02 | 900 | 2 |
| customer_b | 2023-01-01 | 1572 | 1 |

What I've tried:

```
SELECT *
     , SUM(total_order_amount)
           OVER (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY last_order_date RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 7 DAYS PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS total_order_amount_sum
FROM t;
```

and a lateral_join

```
WITH cte_vals AS (


               SELECT *
               FROM (
                 VALUES ('customer_a', '2023-01-01 14:24:18'::timestamp, 250)
                      , ('customer_a', '2023-01-01 14:24:18'::timestamp + INTERVAL '20 HOURS', 250)
                      , ('customer_a', '2023-01-01 14:24:18'::timestamp + INTERVAL '29 HOURS', 900)
                      , ('customer_b', '2023-01-01 14:24:18'::timestamp, 750)
                      , ('customer_b', '2023-01-01 14:24:18'::timestamp + INTERVAL '10 HOURS', 800)
                      , ('customer_b', '2023-01-01 14:24:18'::timestamp + INTERVAL '20 HOURS', 22)
                 ) t(customer, last_order_date, total_order_amount)
               )

SELECT t.*
     , t1.*
FROM cte_vals t

  CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT SUM(total_order_amount) AS total_order_amount_sum
  FROM cte_vals AS t1
  WHERE
      t1.customer = t.customer
  AND t1.last_order_date
        BETWEEN t.last_order_date
        AND t.last_order_date + INTERVAL '24 HOURS'
  )           t1
```

the first of which gives me an error (mainly to do with Snowflake not support sliding window functions) but I'm not sure how I'd even apply the `range` on my chosen interval here.

the latter gives me an incorrect summed amount.

| CUSTOMER | LAST_ORDER_DATE | TOTAL_ORDER_AMOUNT | TOTAL_ORDER_AMOUNT_SUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| customer_a | 2023-01-01 14:24:18.000000000 +00:00 | 250 | 500 |
| customer_a | 2023-01-02 10:24:18.000000000 +00:00 | 250 | 1150 |
| customer_a | 2023-01-02 19:24:18.000000000 +00:00 | 900 | 900 |
| customer_b | 2023-01-01 14:24:18.000000000 +00:00 | 750 | 1572 |
| customer_b | 2023-01-02 10:24:18.000000000 +00:00 | 22 | 22 |
| customer_b | 2023-01-02 00:24:18.000000000 +00:00 | 800 | 822 |

### Source data

```
SELECT *
               FROM (
                 VALUES ('customer_a', '2023-01-01 14:24:18'::timestamp, 250)
                      , ('customer_a', '2023-01-01 14:24:18'::timestamp + INTERVAL '20 HOURS', 250)
                      , ('customer_a', '2023-01-01 14:24:18'::timestamp + INTERVAL '29 HOURS', 900)
                      , ('customer_b', '2023-01-01 14:24:18'::timestamp, 750)
                      , ('customer_b', '2023-01-01 14:24:18'::timestamp + INTERVAL '10 HOURS', 800)
                      , ('customer_b', '2023-01-01 14:24:18'::timestamp + INTERVAL '20 HOURS', 22)
                 ) t(customer, last_order_date, total_order_amount)
```

### Step 1

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  VALUES ('customer_a', '2023-01-01 14:24:18'::timestamp, 250, 1)
       , ('customer_a', '2023-01-01 14:24:18'::timestamp + INTERVAL '20 HOURS', 250, 1)
       , ('customer_a', '2023-01-01 14:24:18'::timestamp + INTERVAL '29 HOURS', 900, 2)
       , ('customer_b', '2023-01-01 14:24:18'::timestamp, 750, 1)
       , ('customer_b', '2023-01-01 14:24:18'::timestamp + INTERVAL '25 HOURS', 800, 1)
       , ('customer_b', '2023-01-01 14:24:18'::timestamp + INTERVAL '29 HOURS', 22, 1)
  ) t(customer, last_order_date, total_order_amount, range_48_hour_key)
```

### Expected output

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  VALUES ('customer_a', '2023-01-01', 500, 1)
       , ('customer_a', '2023-01-02', 900, 2)
       , ('customer_b', '2023-01-01', 1572, 1)
  ) t(customer, date, total_order_amount_sum, range_48_hour_key)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can calculate the running sum of the difference for all orders of a customer.

And the use integer divison of 86400 (24 h inseconds) to get your rank

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT CUSTOMER, LAST_ORDER_DATE, TOTAL_ORDER_AMOUNT
     ,TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,
   LAG(LAST_ORDER_DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY CUSTOMER ORDER BY LAST_ORDER_DATE)
  ,LAST_ORDER_DATE)  diff
    
FROM t), CTE2 as (
  SELECT CUSTOMER, LAST_ORDER_DATE, TOTAL_ORDER_AMOUNT,
  FLOOR(SUM(COaLESCE(diff,0)) OVER(PARTITION BY CUSTOMER ORDER BY LAST_ORDER_DATE) / 86400) rnk 
  FROM CTE)
SELECT CUSTOMER, MIN(LAST_ORDER_DATE) as LAST_ORDER_DATE, SUM(TOTAL_ORDER_AMOUNT) TOTAL_ORDER_AMOUNT_in_24h
FROM CTE2 
GROUP BY CUSTOMER,rnk
```

| CUSTOMER | LAST_ORDER_DATE | TOTAL_ORDER_AMOUNT_in_24h |
| --- | --- | --- |
| customer_a | 2023-01-01 14:24:18 | 500 |
| customer_a | 2023-01-02 19:24:18 | 900 |
| customer_b | 2023-01-01 14:24:18 | 1572 |

Comment: this looks ace! thanks I'll test it first thing tomorrow thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
select customer,
       min(last_order_date) date_,
       sum(total_order_amount) total,
       grp+1 RANGE_48_HOUR_KEY, /* or */ rank() over (partition by customer order by grp) range
from
(
  select *,
    datediff(second, min(last_order_date) over (partition by customer), last_order_date)/ (60*60*24) grp
  from table_name
) t
group by customer, grp
order by customer, min(last_order_date)
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Rp3Npxhe) on sql server, I think it will work for Snowflake.

You may just need to use `floor((datediff(second, min(last_order_date) over (partition by customer), last_order_date)/ (60*60*24),0) grp` for Snowflake.

output:

[image]

Comment: a fellow SQL Server man :) thanks I'll see if your approach works but I much prefer nbk's

Comment: the rank approach worked thanks Ahmed!